# Cant start an instance openstack

Tags: logging, openstack, openstack-nova, devstack

I used devstack to setup openstack using `./stack.sh`. I didn't add any files or change anything, everything is default. When I get on the dashboard and click launch on the included `cirros` image I get

```
Error: Failed to launch instance "test":
Please try again later [ Error: No valid host was found. ].
```

I've searched a lot of places for an answer and most of the answers involve checking my logs.

That brings me to my second question: I do not know why I don't have a `/var/log/nova` directory on my server. I'm new to systems administration and even newer to OpenStack. So i don't have much to add besides that.

Comment: What flavor is the instance you are trying to create?

Answer (score 1):

Devstack does not log to files, it creates a screen session that contains all the services, and each service logs to the console.

To access logs you need to get into your devstack directory and type this command:

```
$ ./rejoin-stack.sh
```

This will put you in a `screen` session. Now you can find the session for nova-compute and that will have your logs. To select a session type Ctrl+A and then " (the double-quote character). A list of sessions will be shown, from where you can select one. The nova-compute session I believe is called "n-cpu". To exit the screen session type Ctrl+A and then "d". There are a lot more things you can do in a screen session, look up the documentation for the screen utility for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Check if all openstack services are up, also you can start only nova services from following command:

```
cd /etc/int.d && for i in $( ls nova-*); do service $i restart; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not familiar with devstack deployments but for the *Host Error*.

First see if all services are running on not. Particularly `nova`:

```
openstack-service status
```

All services should be up and running.

Now second thing, run the following command on the compute nodes:

```
hostname
```

This should display hostname of the node.

Now run the following on controller node:

```
nova availability-zone-list
```

This should display all the hosts (by their hostnames) registered with OpenStack Nova.
Particularly there might be some issue here with host details and I guess you are missing the details here.

If this is the case, then look for how to adding compute hosts in Openstack Nova in the manuals.